# Fail to redirect requests to specific url to localhost

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a server that listens on `http://localhost:3000` and I want to forward all requests to `http://api.lingualeo.com/addword` from Chrome extension (some JSON data) to `http://localhost:3000`.

What I did:

```
# sysctl -w net/ipv4/conf/all/route_localnet=1
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string \
    --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp \
    -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:3000
```

But it didn't work and my `iptables -nvL` was clean.

I tried:

```
# iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m string \
    --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp \
    -o lo -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000</code>
```

and that too didn't work and my `iptables -nvL` was clean.

However, **blocking** requests to `http://api.lingualeo.com/addword` with the following command:

```
# iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m string \
    --string "POST /addword?port=1001" --algo kmp -j DROP
```

worked as expected.

OS: archlinux x64